# A memory leak-free RAII wrapper around two raw pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, raii

As a practice of implementing RAII-enabled class, I prepared a class called `DynamicWallet` that wraps around two raw pointers. I am well aware that using smart pointers instead of raw pointers could save a lot of hassles but the point of the practice is to get down to gory details so I would like to keep them. Given this requirement (i.e., to use raw pointers), is the follow class good enough to handle all edge cases (e.g., self-assignment/OOM exceptions/etc.)?

```
class DynamicWallet {
private:
  int *ptr0 = nullptr;
  int *ptr1 = nullptr;
  size_t wallet_size = 0;

  void freePtrs() noexcept {
    free(ptr0);
    free(ptr1);
  }

  void mallocPtrs() {

    if (wallet_size == 0) {
      // man malloc: If size is 0, then malloc() returns either NULL, or a
      // unique pointer value that can later be successfully passed to free().
      // To avoid confusion and possible issue with memcpy(), etc., let's just
      // ban this
      throw invalid_argument("wallet_size must be positive");
    }
    ptr0 = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * wallet_size);
    if (ptr0 == nullptr) {
      throw bad_alloc();
    }
    ptr1 = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * wallet_size);
    if (ptr1 == nullptr) {
      free(ptr0);
      ptr0 = nullptr;
      throw bad_alloc();
    }
  }

public:
  DynamicWallet(size_t wallet_size) {

    cout << "DynamicWallet (" << wallet_size << ") called" << endl;
    this->wallet_size = wallet_size;
    mallocPtrs();
  }

  // Copy constructor
  DynamicWallet(const DynamicWallet &rhs) {
    wallet_size = rhs.wallet_size;
    mallocPtrs();
    memcpy(ptr0, rhs.ptr0, sizeof(int) * wallet_size);
    memcpy(ptr1, rhs.ptr1, sizeof(int) * wallet_size);
    cout << "copy constructor called" << endl;
  }

  // Copy assignment operator
  DynamicWallet &operator=(const DynamicWallet &rhs) {
    cout << "copy assignment operator called";
    if (this != &rhs) {                     // not a self-assignment
      if (wallet_size != rhs.wallet_size) { // resource cannot be reused
        cout << " and wallet resized";
        freePtrs();
        wallet_size = rhs.wallet_size;
        mallocPtrs();
      } else {
        cout << " and previous memory reused for new data";
      }
      memcpy(ptr0, rhs.ptr0, sizeof(int) * wallet_size);
      memcpy(ptr1, rhs.ptr1, sizeof(int) * wallet_size);

    } else {
      cout << " but it is a self-assignment";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return *this;
  }

  int &operator()(size_t i, size_t j) {
    if (i > 1 || j >= wallet_size) {
      throw out_of_range("");
    }
    return (i == 0 ? ptr0[j] : ptr1[j]);
  }

  ~DynamicWallet() noexcept { freePtrs(); }
};
```

Answer (score 7):

Wanting to learn the ins and outs of making a good RAII type is great, but choosing to do so via low-level memory management is not a good idea. At that level, things are much, *much*, ***MUCH*** more complicated than you think.

I’m going to assume the proper use of `std::` everywhere it’s required, but even with that, there are some subtle bugs. In practice, on most platforms, most of these bugs will be imperceptible; everything will appear to “work”. But you may find that it won’t work in `constexpr` contexts (not that it would anyway, so long as you’re using `malloc()`), because `constexpr` contexts do not tolerate undefined behaviour. You may also find it fails static analysis.

A lot of the problems stem from the use of `malloc()`. `malloc()` is not a C++ function. It is a C library function. Just because the C++ standard library wraps a C function, that does not make the function a good idea to use in C++. `exit()`, for example; you should never, ever use `exit()` in a C++ program. `malloc()` is only a little better; you *can* use `malloc()` in a C++ program… but you need to do so very, very carefully.

The reason `malloc()` causes problems is because it only allocates memory. It does not create any objects. When you do:

```
auto n = *static_cast<int*>(std::malloc(sizeof(int)));
```

you do not have an `int`. Let me repeat that. `n` is *not* an `int`.

What you have is a bag of bits that is the correct size and alignment for an `int`. But there is no `int` in there.

To actually get a dynamically allocated `int`, you would have to do:

```
auto temp_n = *static_cast<int*>(std::malloc(sizeof(int)));
auto n = *(::new (static_cast<void*>(&temp_n)) int{});

// or, more sensibly:
auto p = std::malloc(sizeof(int));
auto n = *(::new (p) int);
```

That call to placement-`new` (or some equivalent) is ***NOT*** optional. Without it, you simply don’t have an `int`. In practice, things will probably “work” without it… but it’s wrong. Plain wrong. And as with all undefined behaviour, even if it happens to “work” today, it may not work tomorrow.

With me so far? To recap:

1. Memory allocation functions (like `malloc()`) allocate memory (duh, right?). But… and this is the important part… **that is *all* they do**.
2. Memory allocation functions do not create objects.
3. After you have obtained (appropriately sized and aligned) memory from a memory allocation function, you need to actually create objects in it before you have any objects you can use.

Because you are dealing with arrays, it would probably be easier to do:

```
ptr0 = static_cast<int*>(std::malloc(sizeof(int) * wallet_size));
std::ranges::uninitialized_default_construct_n(ptr0, wallet_size);
```

Without `uninitialized_default_construct_n()`, you would *technically* have to do:

```
ptr0 = static_cast<int*>(std::malloc(sizeof(int) * wallet_size));

auto i = std::size_t{0};

try
{
    for (; i < wallet_size; ++i)
        (void)(::new (ptr0 + i) int);
}
catch (...)
{
    for (; i != 0; --i)
        (ptr0 + (i - 1))->~int();

    throw;
}
```

That is, you need to construct *each `int`* in the array, and if one of the constructions fails, you need to clean up the constructions that were already done. (You also need to free the pointer, obvs, but I’m ignoring that for now.)

Of course, `int` constructions can never fail, so you could get away without the `try`-`catch` and clean-up loop. Still, the loop is ugly, and `uninitialized_default_construct_n()` is self-documenting.

Okay, so, all you need to do is make sure to initialize all the `int`s in the memory allocated by `malloc()`, and no more UB, right?

Sorry, no. There’s still more UB to deal with. Hey, you wanted the gory details.

The problem here is that default-constructing `int`s will create valid `int` objects… but with indeterminate values. That is not problem if you simply overwrite those values (as you do in your copy constructor). But if you *don’t* overwrite those values (as in your default constructor), and then read them, boom. UB.

Again, in practice, on just about any platform you will ever use, things will “work”. But, again, it’s still indisputably wrong, and may fail catastrophically in the future, or on some unexpected or exotic hardware. (I have been reminded that one of the platforms it might conceivable fail on is [IA-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA-64)… which is hardly exotic! IA-64 `int`s have a trap representation. If you don’t clear them before trying to read them… boom.) Or it may fail to compile in `constexpr` contexts, or fail static analysis.

Well, the very simple solution is not to default-initialize, but to value-initialize instead. In other words:

```
int i;      // This is default-initialization.
            //
            // i is a legit int, but its value is indeterminate.
            // You can overwrite it, but you can't read it.

int j{};    // This is value-initialization.
            //
            // j is a legit int, with value 0.
```

To get this effect with placement-`new`, you just add the braces:

```
auto p = std::malloc(sizeof(int));
auto n = *(::new (p) int{});
// n is a legit int, with value 0, perfectly safe to use.
```

(Okay, technically, what’s happening above is actually direct-list-initialization, but since the parentheses are empty, it falls back to value-initialization… gory details, amirite?)

And with the proper library function:

```
ptr0 = static_cast<int*>(std::malloc(sizeof(int) * wallet_size));
std::ranges::uninitialized_value_construct_n(ptr0, wallet_size);
// yes, literally just replace "default_construct" with "value_construct"
```

***NOW*** you have an array of actual `int` objects that are safe to use, reading and writing.

So, to recap so far, to dynamically allocate *and initialize* a single `int` here are your options:

```
// With malloc (or, generally, any allocation function) ================

ptr0 = static_cast<int*>(std::malloc(sizeof(int))); // allocate
(void)(::new (static_cast<void*>(ptr0)) int{});     // initialize
// or:
ptr0 = static_cast<int*>(std::malloc(sizeof(int))); // allocate
std::ranges::construct_at(ptr0);                    // initialize

// If you want to initialize to a specific value, like 42,
// replace the initialize line with:
ptr0 = static_cast<int*>(std::malloc(sizeof(int))); // allocate
(void)(::new (static_cast<void*>(ptr0)) int{42});   // initialize
// or:
ptr0 = static_cast<int*>(std::malloc(sizeof(int))); // allocate
std::ranges::construct_at(ptr0, 42);                // initialize

// If you want an int with a value to be set BUT NOT READ later,
// replace the initialize line with:
ptr0 = static_cast<int*>(std::malloc(sizeof(int))); // allocate
(void)(::new (static_cast<void*>(ptr0)) int);       // initialize
// or:
ptr0 = static_cast<int*>(std::malloc(sizeof(int)));         // allocate
std::ranges::uninitialized_default_construct_n(ptr0, 1);    // initialize

// With new, non-throwing ==============================================

ptr0 = new (std::nothrow) int{};     // allocate & initialize

// If you want to initialize to a specific value, like 42:
ptr0 = new (std::nothrow) int{42};   // allocate & initialize

// If you want an int with a value to be set BUT NOT READ later:
ptr0 = new (std::nothrow) int;       // allocate & initialize
```

You may be wondering with `(void)(::new (static_cast<void*>(ptr0)) int{});`:

1. why cast `ptr0` to `void*`
2. why `::new` and not just `new`; and
3. why cast the whole expression to `void`.

The reason for 1 and 2 is to prevent overloads from hijacking the allocation. If you don’t force the global `new`, or if you don’t ensure the pointer is a pointer to `void`, you may not get the proper placement-`new` function.

The reason for 3 is that the placement-`new` operation is `[[nodiscard]]`, but we don’t need the return value, so we need to shut the warning up.

You can see why non-throwing `new` is better in every case above, even without considering all the other benefits. And we haven’t even looked at *de*allocation yet.

To dynamically allocate *and initialize* an array of `int`s:

```
// With malloc (or, generally, any allocation function) ================

ptr0 = static_cast<int*>(std::malloc(sizeof(int) * wallet_size));   // allocate
// ******** initialize with a loop ********
// or:
std::ranges::uninitialized_value_construct_n(ptr0, wallet_size);    // initialize

// If you want an int with a value to be set BUT NOT READ later,
// replace the initialize line with:
ptr0 = static_cast<int*>(std::malloc(sizeof(int) * wallet_size));   // allocate
// ******** initialize with a loop ********
// or:
std::ranges::uninitialized_default_construct_n(ptr0, wallet_size);  // initialize

// With new, non-throwing ==============================================

ptr0 = new (std::nothrow) int[wallet_size] {};  // allocate & initialize

// If you want an int with a value to be set BUT NOT READ later:
ptr0 = new (std::nothrow) int[wallet_size];       // allocate & initialize
```

And of course, what gets allocated, must be deallocated. But also de-initialized.

So to clean up a single `int`:

```
// With free (or, generally, any deallocation function) ================

if (ptr0)           // need to check for nullptr!
                    // (at least for the destructor/destroy_at() call)
{
    ptr0->~int();       // de-initialize
    // or:
    std::ranges::destroy_at(ptr0);  // de-initialize

    std::free(ptr0);    // de-allocate
}

// With delete =========================================================

delete ptr0;
```

And to clean up an array of `int`s:

```
// With free (or, generally, any deallocation function) ================

if (ptr0)           // need to check for nullptr!
                    // (at least for the destroy_n() call)
{
    std::ranges::destroy_n(ptr0, wallet_size);  // de-initialize
    std::free(ptr0);                            // de-allocate
}

// With delete =========================================================

delete[] ptr0;
```

Okay, now with all that covered, let’s look at the actual code.

```
  int *ptr0 = nullptr;
  int *ptr1 = nullptr;
```

You are using C-style declarator layout. [That is discouraged in C++](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#nl18-use-c-style-declarator-layout). C++ style is keep the type stuff together, so `int* ptr0 = nullptr;`.

```
  void mallocPtrs() {

    if (wallet_size == 0) {
      // man malloc: If size is 0, then malloc() returns either NULL, or a
      // unique pointer value that can later be successfully passed to free().
      // To avoid confusion and possible issue with memcpy(), etc., let's just
      // ban this
      throw invalid_argument("wallet_size must be positive");
    }
    ptr0 = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * wallet_size);
    if (ptr0 == nullptr) {
      throw bad_alloc();
    }
    ptr1 = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * wallet_size);
    if (ptr1 == nullptr) {
      free(ptr0);
      ptr0 = nullptr;
      throw bad_alloc();
    }
  }
```

We’ll need to apply all the stuff about object initialization here, but first, let’s see if we can improve the structure of this function a bit.

The error handling need not be repeated. You could refactor to something like this:

```
auto mallocPtrs() -> void
{
    if (wallet_size == 0)
        throw std::invalid_argument{"wallet_size must be positive"};

    ptr0 = static_cast<int*>(std::malloc(sizeof(int) * wallet_size));

    // The if check is technically not necessary. If you're failing, there no
    // little point worrying about efficiency. You're about to throw anyway,
    // so efficiency is already out the window. But, meh.
    if (ptr0 != nullptr)
        ptr1 = static_cast<int*>(std::malloc(sizeof(int) * wallet_size));

    if (ptr0 == nullptr or ptr1 == nullptr)
    {
        std::free(ptr0);
        std::free(ptr1);

        throw std::bad_alloc{};
    }
}
```

Now, though, you need to take object initialization into account, and that makes things *much* more complicated, because you have to consider failure at *both* stages of object creation: allocation and initialization. You will have to de-initialize each object if-and-only-if they were successfully initialized, on top of de-allocation. Also, remember to *value* initialize, not default initialize.

This is where the rubber hits the road. You wanted to learn low-level RAII coding? You wanted to get gory? Here you go. Writing this function *properly*, with no RAII helpers like smart pointers, and so that it will even work with evil throwing types (not just `int`!), that will put hair on your knuckles, and make a real C++ coder out of you. Have at it!

```
  DynamicWallet(size_t wallet_size) {

    cout << "DynamicWallet (" << wallet_size << ") called" << endl;
    this->wallet_size = wallet_size;
    mallocPtrs();
  }
```

Single-argument constructors should (almost) always be `explicit`. You certainly don’t want implicit conversions from integers here.

I’m not sure the `mallocPtrs()` helper function is all that helpful. As I see it, this is the one and only function that will ever need to value-initialize the arrays (as I’ll explain with the copy constructor momentarily). The entirety of that function could just as well be right here.

You could avoid the ugly `this->` prefix by using a better naming convention for your private data members. Some people like to prefix `m_`. Others suffix `_`. I prefer to prefix `_`. Doesn’t really matter what you choose.

Alternately, you could do this, I suppose:

```
explicit DynamicWallet(std::size_t wallet_size)
    : wallet_size{wallet_size}
{
    // ...
}
```

You should probably initialize `wallet_size` in the initializer list anyway. Not that it will make much difference, because you’re about to do *two* allocations, so efficiency is hardly a big concern.

Incidentally, I know this is mostly just a learning exercise to study the ways of RAII, so having two allocations makes sense for that… but if this were a real-world type, then unless there were reasons why it won’t work, I would suggest combining the two allocations into one. In other words, just allocate a single array that is twice the size of `wallet_size`.

Also, [don’t use `endl`](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#slio50-avoid-endl). Like, ever. It’s basically always wrong.

The output statement already ends with a string literal anyway. Just do:

```
std::cout << "DynamicWallet (" << wallet_size << ") called\n";
```

Okay, the constructor above was maybe the third biggest challenge. Now onto the second biggest challenge: the copy constructor.

Now, the easiest way to write the copy constructor would be:

```
DynamicWallet(DynamicWallet const& rhs)
    // take advantage of constructor delegation
    : DynamicWallet{rhs.wallet_size}
{
    std::ranges::copy_n(rhs.ptr0, wallet_size, ptr0);
    std::ranges::copy_n(rhs.ptr1, wallet_size, ptr1);

    std::cout << "copy constructor called\n";
}
```

This is perfectly fine, and will work in all circumstances, even if one of the copy operations could throw (which won’t happen for `int`, obviously, but yanno).

The problem is: this isn’t the most *efficient* pattern.

The delegated constructor will create the two arrays, and fill them with zeroes… which will then be promptly written over with the copies. This is harmless, but wasteful.

What you want instead is to *almost* duplicate the previous constructor, but instead of value-initializing, default-initialize instead. Default-initialization is a no-op for `int`, but it does reify the `int`, so you can then write over it.

***OR***, another option is to use `std::ranges::uninitialized_copy_n()`. Ignoring the error-handling (which is where all the fun is!) it would look something like this:

```
ptr0 = static_cast<int*>(std::malloc(sizeof(int) * wallet_size));
std::ranges::uninitialized_copy_n(rhs.ptr0, wallet_size, ptr0, ptr0 + wallet_size);
```

Finally: don’t use `memcpy()`. The standard library `copy()` or `copy_n()` are both superior in every way. With any decent compiler/library pair, they will fall back on `memcpy()` *or better* if they can.

And now, onto the number one biggest challenge, the copy assignment operator.

Now, the *simple* pattern for a copy assignment operator is the copy-and-swap idiom:

```
auto operator=(DynamicWallet const& rhs) -> DynamicWallet&
{
    auto temp = rhs; // copy construct

    // You should have a swap function, and it should be noexcept, but it
    // need not be part of the public interface.
    swap(*this, temp);

    return *this;
}
```

Assuming your copy constructor is correct, and your swap function is correct (and no-fail), then this will *always* work.

It is, however, not the most efficient solution. Thus you might want to write something manually, as you have. However, your solution is… not great.

The key problem with your solution is here:

```
      if (wallet_size != rhs.wallet_size) { // resource cannot be reused
        cout << " and wallet resized";
        freePtrs();
        wallet_size = rhs.wallet_size;
        mallocPtrs();
      } else {
```

So, what happens if `mallocPtrs()` fails? You’ve already freed the memory for `this`. You’ve left the object in a hopelessly broken state. I could do:

```
auto a = DynamicWallet{123};
auto b = DynamicWallet{456};

try
{
    a = b;  // assume this fails
}
catch (...)
{
    // handle the exception and continue
}

std::cout << a(0, 1); // CRASH!

// Even without the line above, you will still
// end up with a double-free at destruction.
```

This is why the copy-and-swap idiom exists: all the chicanery required to update the object is done *before* the object itself is ever touched (and then the swap should always be no-fail, so… it won’t fail).

So you need to allocate the new memory *before* you touch the existing memory. You need to allocate *both* of those arrays, and get them to a point where nothing further can fail. Basically, you need to rewrite the copy constructor right there in that `if` block.

But wait, there’s more! Up to this point, you could just do the copy-and-swap dance only in that `if` block, and it would be as efficient as possible. However… you reuse the memory if it’s the same size… but have you considered: what if the existing memory is larger than necessary? Why throw it away and reallocate a smaller block? You have 3 cases (ignoring self-assignment): the two arrays have the same size, which you handle fine already… `rhs` is larger, which would require reallocation (but more carefully than you have now! don’t free before you know you’re safe!)… and `rhs` is smaller, where you don’t need to reallocate, because you can just use parts of the arrays. This would require a refactor where you add capacity data for each array, but it would mean incredible performance gains whenever copying over large data with smaller data.

And if you’re doing that, you will, in the future, be able to detect the actually-allocated size at allocation time, and use it later if needed. This will give you “re-allocation” functionality, but orders of magnitude faster than with the C library functions.

This would be one of the most challenging things you could code in C++ that doesn’t involve concurrency. I’ve been programming C++ since before the first standard, and even I don’t think I could fire off this copy assignment operator without any RAII helper types (like smart pointers) in one go, especially if you write it keeping types more complex than `int` in mind.

The last thing I would suggest is adding the move operations. Move construction is easy… once you decide what constitutes a default “empty” state. Move assignment will range from trivial to brain-melting hard, depending on which cases you want to handle.

### Summary

- In C++, you deal with **objects**… not memory.
- Objects *need* memory (usually), but are more than mere memory.
- Objects don’t exist unless initialized/constructed/created/reified. They continue to exist until destroyed.
- Don’t use `malloc()`/`free()`. They are not C++ functions, they are C functions.
- If you are avoiding `new` to avoid exceptions, just use `std::nothrow`.
- `new`/`delete` is not only safer and easier than `malloc()`/`free()`, it is also potentially much faster.
- But if you want to play with low-level code, `new`/`delete` will still give you plenty to fret over.
- Generally, don’t use a C library function when a C++ function that does “the same thing” exists. The C++ function will *always* be safer, and almost always faster… never slower. (It is a long-debunked myth that “low-level C code” is faster than idiomatic C++.)
- If you really, really want to use `malloc()`/`free()`, remember they only allocate memory. They do not create objects. You have to do that manually.
- If you manually initialize objects, then you also have to manually destroy them.
- The trick to error handling is to look at every statement, and every expression within each statement, and ask “what happens if an exception is thrown here?” Proper RAII types, like smart pointers, always answer with “everything will just work”, which is why we use them. If you want to eschew that, then it becomes your responsibility. You need to look at every object in scope, including `this`, and figure out what state they will be in after the exception is thrown.
- In your main constructor, you have 4 major tasks: allocate the two arrays, and initialize the elements of each array. You should be prepared for any of those tasks to fail (though, the latter won’t fail for `int`), and clean up any completed tasks.
- In your copy constructor, you have *6* major tasks: allocate the two arrays, initialize the elements of the two arrays, and then copy the values into the two arrays. You can combine the initialization and copying into a single operation with `uninitialized_copy()` or some such function. But still, any task may fail, and if so, all completed tasks must be cleaned up.
- Your copy assignment operator will be much, much more complicated, due to the branching possibilities. In every case, you should avoid touching `this` until all the dangerous stuff is done, so that, on failure, `this` remains as it was initially. That gives you the strong exception guarantee. You can get some more performance if you don’t want to offer the strong guarantee, and allow `this` to be modified even in the event of an exception, but you still need to leave `this` in a valid state regardless. Might as well stick with the strong exception guarantee.
- You should add move operations. Move construction will be easy. Move assignment? Very, very hard.
- A very important consideration not mentioned so far is testability. Testing code that uses C library functions like `malloc()` is… hard. Not impossible, but not easy, and usually involves getting messy with macros. Testing code that uses `new`… very easy. But even better would be to make the type allocator-aware, so you could just pop in an instrumented allocator for testing. Or even a `constexpr` allocator, so you can test in a `constexpr` context, which would catch all UB.
- In general, there is a lot of C smell in your code, both stylistically and in your choice of functions (like `malloc()` over `new`, and `memcpy()` over `copy()`). If you want to write C, then by all means do so. But if you want to write C++, you will find things much easier, and your code vastly better, if you let go of your C habits and embrace C++. Idiomatic C++ is much, *much* easier to write, much, *much* safer, and often even faster than even well-written C.

### Questions

#### The C and C++ object models

Response to question in [comment #1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/286921/a-memory-leak-free-raii-wrapper-around-two-raw-pointers#comment571830_287161):

> … I think this is common sense in C: for sure `malloc()` gives us a pointer only and nothing more…

That is not correct, and that is indeed the very important point I was trying to make. The object models in C and C++ are *very* different. C and C++ are *not* the same, or even “similar” languages. Whenever you see someone trying to jam them together into the chimeric “C/C++”, that’s a pretty good indicator that person doesn’t know what they’re doing.

In C, an object is literally just a chunk of memory. Nothing more. It “gains” a type when you write to it (so, in fact, you have the object before the object has a type… which would be nonsensical in the C++ model). It keeps that type only until you write to it with a different type. (I’m simplifying a bit, but not much.) In C, an object lifetime is defined as its storage duration.

So, in C, `malloc(sizeof(int))` *literally* ***does*** create an `int`. (Again, simplifying, but basically true.) Objects are created by allocation functions (among other things… yet again, simplifying). Object lifetime equals storage duration. This should make sense, because C has no constructors or destructors. Objects begin and end when their storage begins and ends. (See [C object model](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object) and [lifetime in C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/lifetime).)

None of the above is true in C++ (except there’s a catch! gory details!). In C++ objects are *not* just memory locations. Objects are *not* created by allocation functions (again, catch!). Object lifetime does *not* (necessarily!) equal storage lifetime; object lifetime is a subset of the storage duration. In C++, objects don’t exist until they are constructed, which normally happens automatically, but sometimes needs to be done manually. And they end when they are destroyed. Object lifetime is defined by the constructor/destructor calls. Before the constructor there is no object. After the destructor there is no object.

For more details about the above, see [C++ object model](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object) and [lifetime in C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime).

Now, I mentioned a catch: the so-called “[implicit lifetime types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ImplicitLifetimeType)”. Basically, the C types. For compatibility reasons, C++ has allowed you to *not* construct `int`s… so `malloc(sizeof(int))` actually does create an `int` in C++, too, so legal C code is also legal C++ code. Except… maybe not?!

You see, things are changing. Note the defect report and resolution at the bottom of the [implicit lifetime reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ImplicitLifetimeType). Also, note there are [new functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder)—and even more coming in [C++23](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/start_lifetime_as)—to actually create “implicit” lifetime types. Why? The answer is very complicated, and has to do with competing pressures of tightening up the type system, while making previously dangerous code safe(r).

I recommend avoiding the whole quagmire, and especially avoid writing code that may be legal *now*… but may be retroactively declared invalid (again let me point at that defect report at the bottom of the implicit lifetime page; it *retroactively* breaks code before C++20). Implicit lifetime is just one of the ways C++ tries accommodate C, so it can at least *partially* support direct inclusion of C code. The *correct* thing to do in C++ is to construct your objects; don’t do that “implicit lifetime” nonsense. Not only will that likely spare you headaches with `constexpr` and static analysis in the future, it will make your code work even for non-trivial types.

Also, as a practical matter, even for implicitly constructed types, you *have* to do something “constructor-ish” before you can use them anyway. You either need to value-initialize or copy-initialize them. You can do those things using C-like semantics and it *may* work… or you can do them with C++ semantics—that is, placement `new` or `construct_at()` or `uninitialized_copy_construct()` or whatever—and it will not only *definitely* work, future-proofed, but will automatically also work for non-trivial types as well.

When I teach C++, I avoid all this absurd complexity by simply saying: Don’t use `malloc()`. It’s a C function. This is C++. Use `new`. That is the correct way in C++. Period.

There are always students who demand to know all the alternatives, exceptions, and dirty, low-level, nitty-gritty details to everything on day one, but in my experience, indulging them is doing them a disservice. You would only confuse and frustrate them. If they continue to insist, well, that’s on them; I won’t stop them, but neither will I help them. If a student wants to screw themselves, that’s their prerogative; it is not my role as a teacher to hand them the screwdriver.

Only much, much later, when I start talking about writing your own allocator-aware types (and much, much, *much* later, when talking about heterogeneous computing), would I then consider discussing the discord between allocation and initialization, the object model, and all that other fun stuff. Because, by that point, it’s actually useful information, and they’re ready for it.

#### The basic exception guarantee

Response to question in [comment #2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/286921/a-memory-leak-free-raii-wrapper-around-two-raw-pointers#comment571831_287161):

> let's say I only want/need to achieve *basic exception guarantee*, does the code achieve this?

I’m afraid not.

The *strong* exception guarantee promises that in the event of an exception… *nothing* will change. Whatever state the object was in before the call that triggered the exception, it will be in the exact same state after.

The basic guarantee is weaker in that it does not promise the exact same state, but… and this is the important part… it *does* promise ***a valid state***.

You only have 2 public functions that involve exception guarantees:

1. the copy assignment operator; and
2. the parentheses operator.

The other 3 public functions are all constructors and destructors. Exception guarantees don’t really apply to them, because there either is no state before the call (the constructors), so it’s gibberish to promise to preserve state… or it’s a destructor, which should never throw an exception in any case. (You still do have to make sure any partial work done is cleaned up and everything is always left in a valid state. That is the basic guarantee, which *everything* should have, or I would argue the code is broken. But that—the basic guarantee that *all* code should have—is not what we usually mean when we’re talking about a particular operation/function having the strong/basic guarantee.)

The parentheses operator is fine, because it doesn’t change the object, so even if an exception is thrown, you have the strong guarantee by default.

But the copy assignment operator is problematic. Cutting out all the trace statements and replacing the `memcpy`s with proper copies, this function is:

```
auto operator=(DynamicWallet const& rhs) -> DynamicWallet&
{
    if (this != &rhs)
    {
        if (wallet_size != rhs.wallet_size)
        {
            freePtrs();
            wallet_size = rhs.wallet_size;
            mallocPtrs();                   // a
        }

        std::ranges::copy_n(rhs.ptr0, wallet_size, ptr0);   // b1
        std::ranges::copy_n(rhs.ptr1, wallet_size, ptr1);   // b2
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Now, the only lines that can possibly throw an exception are marked (let’s assume `freePtrs()` cannot throw; it’s used in the destructor, after all).

If either “b1” or “b2” throws, then you lose the strong exception guarantee automatically, because those definitely change the value of the object. *However*, so long as the type being copied (in this case, `int`) offers at least the basic exception guarantee, then you still get the basic exception guarantee overall, because even though the contents of one or both of the arrays has changed, everything is still in a valid state.

The problem is at “a”. By the time you get there, the object’s value has definitely been changed—you’ve just freed the arrays—so *at best* you can only offer the basic guarantee. However, the object is in an *invalid*, broken state. The memory for the two arrays has been freed, but the pointers to that now freed memory are still there. If `mallocPtrs()` throws, you’re in an invalid state, so you can’t even offer the basic guarantee. (In fact, you’re going to crash, because the two pointers point to already freed memory, but at some point, probably in the destructor, they will be freed again.)

You have two options:

1. A valid fallback state.
2. Rearranging risk.

A valid fallback state is a valid state for the object that you can always no-fail fallback to should things go awry. For example, you could say that a valid state for the type is: `wallet_size = 0`, `ptr0 = nullptr`, `ptr1 = nullptr`. This state is *always* no-fail achievable, assuming deallocation and destruction are no-fail, which should always be true. No matter what state you are in, you can always destroy the two arrays, set the pointers to `nullptr`, and `wallet_size` to zero. It will *always* work.

So you could do `freePtrs()`, then try `mallocPtrs()`, and if that fails, zero/null everything, then let the exception propagate. That will mean your object’s data has been completely wiped… but the object is still valid. That’s the basic guarantee.

The downside is that adding a null state to the object can massively increase the complexity. For example, you can’t blindly copy anymore, because you don’t know if you’re copying from a null object, will null array pointers. (The upside is that you get a cheap default state for a default constructor, which can be *very* handy. This is why standard types like `std::string` and `std::vector` work this way.)

The second option is rearranging your risk. Your code currently frees the arrays, and then tries to allocate new ones. If, instead, you *first* allocated new ones, and *then*, only on success, freed the old ones… the problem vanishes. In other words, this:

```
auto operator=(DynamicWallet const& rhs) -> DynamicWallet&
{
    if (this != &rhs)
    {
        if (wallet_size != rhs.wallet_size)
        {
            auto const temp_ptr0 = static_cast<int*>(std::malloc(sizeof(int) * rhs.wallet_size));
            if (temp_ptr0 == nullptr)
                throw std::bad_alloc{};

            auto const temp_ptr1 = static_cast<int*>(std::malloc(sizeof(int) * rhs.wallet_size));
            if (temp_ptr1 == nullptr)
            {
                std::free(temp_ptr0);
                throw std::bad_alloc{};
            }

            // As before, you can simplify the below if you only ever use
            // int or other types that will never throw on copy-construct.
            // In that case, you could simply delete the entire try-catch
            // mess, and put the uninitialized_copy_n() calls after the
            // "nothing can fail from this point" line.
            try
            {
                std::ranges::uninitialized_copy_n(rhs.ptr0, rhs.wallet_size, temp_ptr0, temp_ptr0 + rhs.wallet_size);

                try
                {
                    std::ranges::uninitialized_copy_n(rhs.ptr1, rhs.wallet_size, temp_ptr1, temp_ptr1 + rhs.wallet_size);
                }
                catch (...)
                {
                    std::ranges::destroy_n(ptr0, rhs.wallet_size);

                    throw;
                }
            }
            catch (...)
            {
                std::free(temp_ptr0);
                std::free(temp_ptr1);

                throw;
            }

            // !!! From this point on, nothing can fail !!! //

            std::free(ptr0);
            std::free(ptr1);

            ptr0 = temp_ptr0;
            ptr1 = temp_ptr1;

            wallet_size = rhs.wallet_size;
        }
        else
        {
            std::ranges::copy_n(rhs.ptr0, wallet_size, ptr0);
            std::ranges::copy_n(rhs.ptr1, wallet_size, ptr1);
        }
    }

    return *this;
}
```

The downside of this is that now you have more memory allocated than you technically need. The upside is you get not only the basic guarantee, you get the *strong* guarantee.

This is, in fact, the copy-and-swap idiom… except done the hard way, rather than by just using the existing interface.

As a practical matter it is silly and dangerous to write (literally!!!) 50 lines of complex, expert-level code to do what 3 lines of trivial, obvious-even-to-beginners code does. That’s why the copy-and-swap idiom is almost always the way to go. With just this:

```
auto operator=(DynamicWallet const& rhs) -> DynamicWallet&
{
    auto temp = rhs;
    std::ranges::swap(*this, temp);
    return *this;
}
```

You get basically equivalent performance to the complicated mess above—sometimes slower, sometimes faster!—with essentially zero chance for bugs.

If you really want that extra bit of performance in the case of equal-size array, at the cost of the general case, and only offering the basic exception guarantee:

```
auto operator=(DynamicWallet const& rhs) -> DynamicWallet&
{
    if (this != &rhs)
    {
        if (wallet_size != rhs.wallet_size)
        {
            auto temp = rhs;
            std::ranges::swap(*this, temp);
        }
        else
        {
            std::ranges::copy_n(rhs.ptr0, wallet_size, ptr0);
            std::ranges::copy_n(rhs.ptr1, wallet_size, ptr1);
        }
    }

    return *this;
}
```

This kind of optimization might be worth it for a heavily-used vocabulary type, but as a general principle, you shouldn’t add complexity to code unless it’s worth it.

Comment: Hi @indi the answer is really a detailed and informative one. I am afraid I can reply to each point you made given the length limit of the comment section... Firstly, you said "Let me repeat that. `n` is not an `int`." but I think this is common sense in C: for sure `malloc()` gives us a pointer only and nothing more--pointer points to memory address that holds an int (or NULL if it fails) if we `malloc(sizeof(int))` so I am not sure if this is a point you made to "C++-only" programmer just in case they dont know `malloc()` or you want to convey some deeper opinions that I am unaware of

Comment: The 2nd question I have is: let's say I only want/need to achieve *basic exception guarantee*, does the code achieve this? (well I noticed issue, i should have made `wallet_size` a `ssize_t`  and set it to `-1` in case of `malloc()` failure).

Comment: The 3rd comment I have is: well I actually do have a more complete version that follows the rule of five. But this question is kept simpler intentionally so that we may discuss some points in a more detailed manner. My rule of five version is [here](https://github.com/alex-lt-kong/the-nitty-gritty/blob/main/c-cpp/cpp/01_raii-and-the-rule-of-five/02_raw-pointers-with-raii.cpp), if you find it a good object for review, I may open a new code review question later.

Comment: I will answer your questions by extending the answer above, because there are a lot of gory details to explain, and comments just won’t cut it.

Comment: Thanks @indi , can you add some marks (e.g., *Answer to 1st comment:*) to you answer to my questions so that I can know clearly which are the answers to my questions?

Comment: No problem! I also added a small note about testability to the summary.

Comment: On your response to my first question. `malloc(sizeof(int))` would definitely not create an `int`, it does NOT even create an `int*`. `malloc(sizeof(int))` will be evaluted to `malloc(4)` and it let us have a memory block of 4 bytes and nothing more. I guess you might want to say `(int*)malloc(sizeof(int))` creates an `int`. Well if it does, then what does `(int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 2)` create? It creates two `int`s?

Comment: Most of this answer repeats an urban legend that is, at best, years out of date. The C++ Standard (**[c.malloc]**) *does* in fact use the exact words, “`malloc()`-allocated objects.” It also says the function behaves as in the C standard, which also directly says `malloc()` returns a pointer to “the allocated object.” Therefore, the claim that `malloc()` creates something that doesn’t count as “an object” is not correct, even on the DeathStation 9000. You’re not the first person to repeat this claim, but it’s no longer true (if it ever was).

Comment: Additionally, since `int` is both a trivially-copyable and trivially-assignable type, assigning to each element of the allocated array is safe. More elegant solutions in C++ to initialize a block of memory from `malloc()` would be `std::uninitialized_fill` or `std::uninitialized_copy`.

Comment: “`malloc(sizeof(int))` would definitely not create an `int`…” From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object): “Objects are created by declarations, **allocation functions**, …”. And as @Davislor points out, [the C standard itself confirms that `malloc()` returns pointers to objects](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3): “The lifetime of an allocated object extends from the allocation until the deallocation.”. If you dispute the C standard, you can take it up with WG 14 by filing a defect report. I report what the standard says, not what I want it to say. … 1/2

Comment: … but to actually answer your question, according to [6.7.2.1p20](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p20) (which is technically about flexible array members, but does directly answer the question), yes, `(int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 2)` does create two `int`s. 2/2

Comment: @Davislor I’m not sure what you’re objecting to. I explicitly described implicit lifetime types, which is the kind of objects `malloc()` creates. Or are you claiming that `malloc()` can create *any* kind of C++ object, not just the special unicorn implicit-lifetime types… because that is categorically false.

Comment: I apologize if I’ve misunderstood your points. Since it probably wouldn’t be productive to debate which particular sentences of our answers are not technically correct, I think here’s the big picture. You’re kind of going off on a tangent about why you don’t think the OP should use `malloc()`, but it mostly talks about complicated (and controversial) corner cases when all they’re using is an array of `int`. Everything the code does is safe for an array of `int`.

Comment: And the justification for this is, the Standard says that part of the code is fine, but the committee might make some change that breaks it in the future. That reasoning could apply to anything in the language. But, realistically? I’d be shocked if the next version broke that much existing code. The committee has only rarely made breaking changes of that magnitude. Usually when it has, compilers did not go along with it and kept backward compatibility anyway, and the committee backtracked and blessed what compilers were already doing.

Comment: I’m still not clear on what the objection is, or what I’ve said that is out-of-date or mythological. This is code review; the goal is code that is modern, idiomatic, easy to maintain, and safe… not merely “legal”. Implicit lifetime is *technically* legal by the standard… but there are a *lot* of things that are *technically* legal yet terrible practices that should never be accepted in a code review, let alone encouraged. It’s *technically* legal to throw from a destructor. I would never accept code that does, though. I would also flag C casts, and most macro usage.

Comment: So are you arguing that relying on the implicit lifetime loophole in the object model is a good practice, that should not be called out in a code review? Because I would strongly disagree. That loophole only exists to allow (some) C code to be more-or-less legal C++. You should *never* use it in pure C++… certainly not in the member function of a class! There is literally *nothing* it adds to C++, it solves no problems (except C compatibility, which is a non-problem in pure C++ code), and it creates *massive* safety and maintainability issues.

Comment: As for implicit lifetime never being banned… it is already *effectively* banned in `constexpr` contexts (because no implicit-lifetime function is `constexpr`). And I think you underestimate the language changes that are being discussed right now: see P2759. While unlikely it will ever be *completely* banned, because C compatibility depends on it, there is a move to create “safety profiles” (see P2816). I see no chance of implicit lifetimes being supported in any plausible safe profile (see slide 27 of P2816), which would make them effectively banned in high-quality C++ code in the future.

Comment: In any case, you are misrepresenting my argument. My justification for not accepting code that relies on implicit lifetimes is not “because it might be banned someday”. It is that implicit lifetime is a non-feature—a hole in the type system created explicitly and *only* for C code—it is confusing, it is dangerous, it inhibits maintainability, it encourages shoddy code (shouldn’t be using `malloc()` instead of `new`), no use of it improves code in any way, and, oh yes, incidentally, it might also be effectively banned someday.

Comment: @indi what I said is that `malloc(sizeof(int))` does not directly give us an `int`, I did **not** say `malloc(sizeof(int))` does not give us an object. I remain silent on whether C/C++ standards refer the pointer returned by `malloc()` points an object. But either way, it is fine. My point is that one `malloc(sizeof(int))` does not return an `int`. Otherwise, can I say `malloc(sizeof(int8_t) * 4)` returns an `int`? How about `malloc(sizeof(double))`? it gives us two `int`s?

Comment: @Davislor exactly, the purpose is to make it leak-free and standard-compliant, as for whether `malloc()` *should* be banned in C++, well as long as C++ committee doesn't say it is banned, I think people are free to use whatever "C function"s, especially given that the intention of this code snippet is to manually wrapping C code into an RAII class--more often not, I can't tell my boss/upstream library developer/client: "I dont like your interface using raw pointer/malloc, please convert it to smart pointer/new or I will resign"...

Comment: You are being disingenuous, or dishonest. Nobody said `malloc()` returns an `int`. Obviously it doesn’t because it returns a pointer. Duh. The important point is whether `malloc(sizeof(int))` ***CREATES*** an `int`. Not “returns”; *creates*. This is a *fundamentally* important point, because object lifetime is one of the most important things in C++; it’s what stuff like RAII is built around. Does `malloc(sizeof(int))` create an `int`? In C: yes. In C++: no… unless you consider the implicit lifetime loophole, in which case the answer is “it depends”. Which is a bad answer. 1/2

Comment: Also, nobody said `malloc()` should be banned; that’s just idiotic. Using the implicit lifetime loophole should be banned… not `malloc()`. If you don’t understand what the implicit lifetime loophole is, or why it’s problematic—and you clearly don’t—then the rule is simple: either a) just always use some form of manual initialization (placement `new`, `construct_at()`, `uninitialized_fill()`, etc.) after `malloc()` (and manual destruction before `free()`); or b) just use `new`, which is simpler, safer, faster, more idiomatic, doesn’t require a header include… better in literally every way. 2/2

Comment: @indi if `malloc(sizeof(int))` **CREATES** an `int`, does `malloc(sizeof(char) * 4)`  **CREATES** an `int` too?

Comment: I literally already answered that exact question, and supplied references to the C standard to support the answer. At this point, I have to wonder if you are just trolling. Nevertheless, making the strained assumption that you actually care about the answer, here we go again. `malloc(sizeof(int))` creates an `int` in C, not in C++ (except with the implicit lifetime loophole: *sometimes*). `malloc(sizeof(char) * 4)` creates 4 `char`s in C, not in C++.

Comment: @indi please let me have the C standard reference that specifies for `void *malloc(size_t size)`, it creates an `int` if I call it by passing `malloc(sizeof(int))` and it creates four `char`s if I call it by passing `mallc(sizeof(char) * 4)`. Also please let me know your answer if I call `malloc(sizeof(int) * 1 / 4)`, in your view does it create a fourth of an `int`.

Comment: I already gave the reference *and link* above. If you care (and I doubt you do), you can read through and find it. I have no idea what that last call to `malloc()` creates. If you care (and, again, I doubt you do), you can ask a C expert. Is the C object model silly and illogical? Yes, very much so. It was grafted on as an afterthought, and never really worked. And then that nonsense was partially imported into C++ as the implicit loophole exception… which is why it’s bad, why it should be banned, and why you should never rely on it in C++ code.

Comment: @indi 7.22.3.4 of [C11](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) says "The malloc function allocates space for an object whose size is specified by size ...", nothing more. `malloc(sizoe(double))` doesn't know/care the "object" is 1 `double`, 2 `int32_t`s or 8 `char`s. I am not sure why your understanding of `malloc()` is so twisted yet you are so confident about what you said--perhaps you just try to use gory details to scare noobs away from using C features in C++, but you pick the wrong target this time.

Comment: I am growing quickly fed up with your poor behaviour. I could make up unflattering motives for why *you* insist on sticking to a model that does not comport with the standard, or practice, but I refuse to sink to that level. (Your accusation is also just stupid. First, how would `malloc()` creating objects be *worse* than it not doing so? Second, anything I say about the *C* object model has literally nothing to do with C++.) If you are not mature enough to disagree without being a shithead, say so, so I can quit wasting my time, you can “win”, and I can move on to something more productive.

Comment: Now: 1) You cannot read a technical standard by cherry-picking a section, noting it does *not* say something, ignoring *the entire rest of the document context*, and then declaring: “see? it’s not there!” Because just four sections up, in the section introducing allocation functions: “The lifetime of an allocated object extends from the allocation until the deallocation. **Each such allocation shall yield a pointer to an object** disjoint from any other object.” Thus, `malloc()` creates objects. QED.

Comment: 2) Again, you are picking ideas out of thin air that nobody said. Of course *malloc* doesn’t know anything about the type of the object you are creating. I mean, duh, how could it? There is nothing in its interface that informs it of the type or number of objects you are allocating. This would be crazy in C++ (hence why the implicit lifetime loophole is so problematic), but is perfectly normal in C’s loosey-goosey type system, where objects really only have “effective” types, where a type is basically “what I say it is”, and can change at the drop of a hat. … 1/2

Comment: … In other words, it is not *malloc* that “knows” you are creating an `int`… *you* know you are creating an `int`, because that’s what you’re doing with `malloc(sizeof(int))`. All `malloc()` “knows” is that it is creating an object(s). But *you* know you have created an object whose type is (intended by you to be) `int`… because that’s literally what you just asked to be done. 2/2

Answer (score 5):

#### Fix the Syntax Errors

This code does not compile.  But the intent is clear enough that I can give some feedback.

#### Use Namespaces

You don’t show the complete program, but a class declaration such as this would normally appear in a header file.  If it contains the line `#include <cstdlib>`, it’s technically not portable to use `malloc` or `free`: you’re supposed to write `std::malloc` and `std::free` (although both work on all implementations I’ve tried).  `#include <stdlib.h>` is also supported, and brings all of its identifiers into the global namespace.

In principle, header files shouldn’t bring more names into the global namespace than they need to, since this creates the risk that one of those names will clash with an identifier in the client code.  You don’t need to worry about this as much with the identifiers in `<stdlib.h>`, because they’ve been around since the ’70s and ’80s and programmers know about them.  But it’s best practice in general not to use standard-library functions in headers without `std::`.  You’re either assuming that will work when it might not, or you’re setting that up so it’s guaranteed to work, which could break user code.

So, in a header file, either write `std::free`, or wrap the class inside a `namespace` and declare `using std::free, std::malloc;` within that `namespace`.

#### Prefer `calloc` to `malloc`

Blocks of memory allocated with `calloc()` are zeroed out, which for `int` is equivalent to default-initialization.  This is more consistent with memory-allocation in C++, and the determinism prevents irreproducible bugs.

#### Use `realloc`

Since you’re using the C-style memory-management functions, you should `realloc` the blocks of memory that you intend to re-use and possibly resize.

#### Follow the Rule of Five

If you are moving, not copying, one of these objects, you can optimize away two allocations, deep copies, and deallocations.  This is a big win!  Add a move constructor and move-assignment operator.

#### Add a Swap Operation

You should always do this when it makes sense.  It is very useful for writing `noexecept` constructors and assignment, and especially simplifies lock-free atomic data structures.

Usually, you want to add both a `friend` `std::swap` overload and a `DynamicWallet::swap` member function.

#### You Don’t Need `freePtrs`

Just call `~DynamicWallet();`.

#### Use Existing Member Functions as Building-Blocks

There are some classic techniques to implement, especially, the assignment operator in terms of the copy constructor and either placement `new` or `swap`.  Since you want to re-use the existing memory blocks if possible, you can’t just use the boilerplate, but the principle of using simpler functions as building-blocks still applies, and can greatly reduce how much of your code a maintainer will need to update.

### About An Urban Legend

The claim that your code is unsafe on a technicality is not correct.

The C++ Standard (in section **[c.malloc]**) uses the exact words, “`malloc()`-allocated objects,” as well as incorporating the C standard’s specification, which also says `malloc()` returns “the allocated object.”  Therefore, even under the most pedantic language-lawyering possible, `malloc()` does create an “object.”  All warnings based on the belief that it doesn’t are mistaken.

Additionally, an array of `int` is Plain Old Data: trivially-copyable, trivially-assignable and trivially-destructible.  The memory returned by `malloc()` is guaranteed to be correctly-aligned for `int` or any other basic type.  It is safe to initialize an array obtained from `malloc()` by checking for a null pointer and assigning a value to each element.  There are no hidden gotchas from object lifetimes or anything else to worry about.

You do need to worry about *reading* the memory from `malloc()` before it’s initialized, however.  An `int` is allowed to have trap representations, which cause undefined behavior if you use or even look at them.  This in practice would only be relevant to some obsolete architectures from the 1960s.

I haven’t exhaustively checked the history of both the C and C++ standards, so I don’t know whether there ever was a time the not-an-object interpretation might have been plausible, but I do know that it was never more than a hypothetical concern.  There is no reason to worry about it out in the real world.

#### Extending This to Arbitrary Types

In contrast, some of the concerns *are* extremely valid for types that are not Plain Old Data.

The most elegant way to set uninitialized memory from `malloc()` is `std::uninitialized_fill` or `std::uninitialized_copy`.  The most elegant way to delete all elements before you `free()` it is `std::destroy`, although you need to know the size of the array at compile time.  That is, you could call it on an `int(&)[wallet_size]`, or an `int(*)[wallet_size]` dereferenced with `*` (where `wallet_size` is a `constexpr std::size_t`), but you cannot call `std::destroy` on an `int*`.  Your dynamic pointers should use the more-complex pointer or reference that knows the size, if possible, which also enables `std::begin()`, `std::end()` and `std::size()`, and makes out-of-bounds errors easier to catch.

If you have a dynamic array whose size you do not know at compile-time, and whose elements are not trivially-destructible, you would need a loop that calls `~T()` on each element to correctly destroy them, before you `free()` it.  You also cannot `realloc()` an array unless its elements are trivially-copyable.

In practice, it’s a lot simpler to use `new[]` and `delete[]`.  You might be forced to interact with a library in some other language that requires passing around a pointer it can `free()`, but that’s the only time it’s necessary to use `malloc()`/`calloc()` in C++.  Code that requires `realloc()` can be rewritten to use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: I would even recommend just using `new` and `delete` over `std::malloc()` and friends; the latter only work for trivial types, and might not return correctly aligned memory for the given type.

Comment: @G.Sliepen The question did specify that the point was to practice using the low-level memory functions, but `new[]` and `delete[]` would certainly work as well. The only disadvantage is not having an equivalent of `realloc`. The memory returned by `malloc` or `calloc` is guaranteed to be correctly-alligned for any built-in type, To get `malloc()` to work with non-trivial types, you would need to loop over the array and initialize each element with placement `new`. And of course, loop over them again and call the destructors before freeing the memory.

Comment: Yes I would like to keep `malloc()`/`free()`/etc. intentionally as they never throw exceptions so it requires me the throw/handle exceptions manually, which is also part of the purpose of the task.

Comment: Avoiding exceptions is not a good reason to use `malloc()`/`free()` in C++. If you don’t want exceptions, you should do `new (std::nothrow) int [wallet_size]`. `malloc()`/`free()` is C, not C++; there are very technical reasons why those are plain wrong in C++ (object lifetimes, implicit launder, etc.). They sorta-kinda “work” for `int`, but they are not correct; your code may fail static analysis. Besides, even ignoring the correctness problem, `new` is superior in every way (better alignment, for example). You will even get better re-alloc functionality once P0901 passes.